# Google sheets isformula() equivalent?

Tags: google-sheets

In the new Google sheets, they added custom formula for conditional formatting. I want the cell to be blue if the cell is a value and black if it is a formula ... I've looked through all of the `is` type functions, there doesn't seem to be a `isformula` kind of function.

Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the isFormula is the standard function in new Google Sheets. You don't have to implement yours one.

```
=isFormula(F2:G5)
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there is a hidden built-in function ISFORMULA() from google.
I realized when I deleted my own function and was still working.
I tried it in a new spreadsheet and still works. No cache issue.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there exists a function which could identify if the contents of a cell are populated based on formula or not. But this could be achieved via a small script

```
function isformula(cell) {
  if (cell.getFormula()) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then in conditional formatting you could use `=isformula(A1)` and set the format as you want.

**PS:** The above code snippet works only for the new google sheets

Comment: Did you test this small script, before posting?

Comment: yeah. most probably you are not using the new Google sheets. Here is a working [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ixWdokpFS8mEFe6iKkDJXIb5jnJ7JR6Q0rEc-YPfsLk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I changed the script into `wasFormula` and it didn't work !! I think you hit, by accident, on an undocumented new formula. See my post on Web Applications: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/63262/29140. You seem to pass on an e.parameter, but that's only possible for triggers, like `onOpen` or `onEdit`.

Comment: wow!!! this is interesting.. thanks for sharing this (btw this also works for conditional formatting)

Comment: At this time, ISFORMULA, (case insensitive) is a built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

`=isFormula(A1)` works now, built-in (even though it's hidden).  <sub>(As has already been said by @JuanPérez.)</sub>

**Literal (user-entered) values** can be tested for with `=NOT(OR(isFormula(A1);isBlank(A1)))`.

I created a Google Sheet with tests/ demos:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VZeVSMHbPS8nAx0E4bQlWW9FygPV1R8-nb0i-vKEt3k
*Make a copy…* via the *File* menu if you’d like to play around.
Suggestions for improving the Sheet are welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At this time, ISFORMULA is a Google spreadsheets built-in function and it's currently included in the official documentation - > https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6270316?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

You can just use ISFORMULA(cell)
It's undocumented, but it works.
If you're using Google Sheets with translated formula names, use English name of the formula.
(So for example if AND(...) doesn't work and you have to type ORAZ(...) then remember that ISFORMULA(...) doesn't get translated into CZY.FORMUŁA(...) and has to be written in English instead.)

Comment: Documented here: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6270316?hl=en-CA

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate slightly on @Konstant's answer while ignoring the script there but addressing some of the specifics of the question:

[image: SO23237313 example]

Comment: Any reason why you're not using `isblank()` in the second custom forumla?